# Crawler is creating a table with weird suffix to the name

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

We have an ETL script which reads the data form catalogue and writes in s3 as parquet. We're also calling a crawler to create/update the tables in Athena. However, it is creating table but adding some weird suffix to the table name.

All the files in the folder that I'm crawling are in parquet with the same schema. Also this is happening only when we're calling the crawler from the ETL script.

The script we used to call the crawler

```
glue_client = boto3.client("glue", region_name=args.get("aws_region"))
glue_client.start_crawler(Name=args["crawler_name"])
```

Expected: table_name
Actual: table_name_31e198c8c61861f127ae06487eb14a3f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when ever Glue crawler encounters a duplicate table name in the Glue data catalogue. Refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) which talks about this behaviour :

***If duplicate table names are encountered, the crawler adds a hash string suffix to the name.***

Comment: Thanks. But we can have the same table name in a different database. I was trying to create a metadata table and actual table in the same database resulted this issue. When I change the database, it worked fine.

Comment: in my case is a single parquet file , by add a "_parquet" to name

Comment: Is there a way to surpress this behaviour? I had a table that moved location and now whenever i run the crawler it recreate the table with this annoying suffix